# Git client for remote server

Tags: git, ssh

I have a situation where I need to develop code on a remote server because the compilers for the language I am using exists only that OS (IBM i).

The usual setup is that I ssh into my system, clone a repository into my home directory and develop code in the repository. I can use the command line to make commits, pushes, merges, etc.

I am wondering if it's possible to use a git client like SourceTree or GitHub for Desktop to connect to a remote server over SSH and work for a remote repository (and doesn't clone the remote repository to my local machine).

Comment: You could mount the directory locally with sshfs.

Comment: sshfs works, but it's veeery slooowww!

Comment: Recommended mount options to make sshfs a little bit faster: [`sshfs -o Ciphers=arcfour,compression=no,nonempty,auto_cache,reconnect,workaround=all`](https://serverfault.com/a/751237/438742).